# Crash sending Emoji through an NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurl, emoji

I'm working on squashing some annoying bugs in one of my Swift projects. I'm wondering if there is a way to transfer emoji via HTTP, so that my server side code can save the emoji data for later retrieval. The problem is, when the request is formulated, the app will crash when creating the NSURL/NSURLSession (Not sure which one exactly) if it contains an Emoji.

Is there any way I can have the app not crash when inserting an Emoji, or is there a dedicated way I can have Emojis in HTTP requests?

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "removed/api.php?request=setBio&identification=" + identification + "&bio=" + content).responseJSON { response in
        if let jsonStr = response.result.value {
            let jsonObj = JSON(jsonStr)
            print ("response for bio update: \(jsonObj["response"])")
            self.user.bio = self.bioField.text!
        }
    }
```

If the "content" String contains an emoji, it will crash. Alamofire runs everything through NSUrlSession.

Crash occurs here in Alamofire (apparently it's finding nil while unwrapping an optional value, not sure why. The text isn't nil.)

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString.URLString)!)
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and specific details about the crash (full error message and point out the exact line causing the crash).

Comment: (This could be a UTF-16 / USC-2 handling issue.  Emoji code-points are not in the BMP.)

Comment: @rmaddy Edited post

Comment: Use NSURLComponents.

Comment: @jtbandes How would I go about that? I'd prefer to use Alamofire as well, but I can use whatever is needed.

Comment: It helps you build a URL while taking care of escaping/encoding. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcomponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a really simple solution!

Just add this on to the content variable:

```
.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

and you'll be able to send a request with an emoji in it.

Comment: The problem with that is if your string included a `+` character, it would be incorrectly interpreted as a space character.

Comment: Excellent solution, worked like a charm - for XCode13, I had to modify this to be ```let my_str = "the string".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)!```

Answer (score 1):

You should let Alamofire do the necessary percent escaping of the request:

```
let parameters = ["request": "setBio", "identification": identification, "bio": content]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "removed/api.php", parameters: parameters, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let jsonStr = response.result.value {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Frankly, I used `ParameterEncoding.URLEncodedInURL` above because in your original example, you put these parameters in the URL. Generally with `POST` requests, though, you'd include these parameters in the body of the request, accomplished by omitting the `encoding` parameter, or, somewhat confusingly/paradoxically, by using an `encoding` of `ParameterEncoding.URL`. Including the parameters in the body of the request is more customary and is more secure. But if you *really* must include these parameters in the URL, supply the `.URLEncodedInURL` value for the `encoding`.

But the key message is that Alamofire already knows how to properly percent escape parameters, so let it do so, rather than manually building the URL or the `NSURLRequest` yourself. And, by way of warning, other techniques, such as `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` (with character sets such as`URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`) or `NSURLComponents` are not only less direct, but they also fail to properly percent escape certain requests (though they'd work with the emoji). Regardless, it's better to let Alamofire handle this, as it does percent escaping correctly.